# Slow performance when using a Camera Preview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

My app contains three fragments. I need to keep the user experience fluid so I'm using a the setOffscreenPageLimit() method to keep them all alive in memory.

Problem: when I start a new activity (even empty), It loads slowly. Same when I finish it.

I know this is coming from my Camera Preview fragment because when I comment out the init of the camera, everything runs very smoothly.

Here is how I initialize my camera preview on the OnResume method:

```java
mCamera = GetCameraInstance(currentCameraId);

//-- Set the SurfaceView
preview = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
mSurfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

if (mCamera != null) {

  mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
  mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

When the new activity is started, the surfaceDestroyed method is called which destroys the Camera preview. When the new activity is terminated, the app recreate a camera view again.

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

The time spent on stopPreview() and release() method as seen on traceview. It takes around 700ms to destroy the camera preview.

[Screenshot of Traceview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXfi6.png)

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: About 700ms are spent on destroying and release the camera. 280ms on recreating the camera preview. 
PS: I don't have enough rep to post a screenshot...

Comment: "I don't have enough rep to post a screenshot" -- you are welcome to upload images elsewhere and link to them here. "About 700ms are spent on destroying and release the camera" -- I haven't tried moving either `stopPreview()` or `release()` into a background thread, but that'd be worth an experiment in your case.

Comment: Putting `stopPreview()` and `release()` into a background thread solves this problem. Thanks

Comment: Ah, good. I was worried that one or both would be tied up with the main application thread in such a way that calling them in a background thread would result in some sort of error.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @CommonsWare suggestion, here is how I did it.

First, I placed my mCamera variable in the Application class

```
public Camera mCamera;
```

Then, I placed the AsyncTask in my fragment

```
 private class ControlCameraTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... urls) {

        //--
        if (app.mCamera != null) {
            app.mCamera.stopPreview();
            app.mCamera.release();
            app.mCamera = null;
        } else {
            app.mCamera = GetCameraInstance(currentCameraId);                
            app.mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(app.mSurfaceHolder);
            app.mCamera.startPreview();
        }

        return null;
    }
 }
```

Finally, I just call my AsyncTask on `onResume`and `onPause`methods

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new ControlCameraTask().execute(1);
}
```

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    new ControlCameraTask().execute(1);
}
```

PS: I removed the trycatches for the code to be easily readable.